# Spring Data Neo4j OGM java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/ogm/annotations/EntityFactory

Tags: spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I use following Mave dependencies:

```
    <spring-data-neo4j.version>4.2.0.M1</spring-data-neo4j.version>
    <neo4j-ogm.version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</neo4j-ogm.version>
```

Right now I can't pass my test with a following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/ogm/annotations/EntityFactory
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery$1.apply(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery$1.apply(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate.doInTransaction(TransactionsDelegate.java:58)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:446)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedSessionCreator.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.doInTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.mapToConcreteType(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.execute(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.getChildDecisionsSortedBySumOfCriteriaAvgVotesWeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.decisionwanted.domain.dao.decision.DecisionDaoImpl.getChildDecisionsSortedBySumOfCriteriaAvgVotesWeightWithCoefficients(DecisionDaoImpl.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.getChildDecisionsSortedBySumOfCriteriaAvgVotesWeightWithCoefficients(Unknown Source)
    at com.decisionwanted.domain.DecisionTreeTest.testGetChildDecisionsSortedBySumOfCriteriaAvgVotesWeightWithCoefficients(DecisionTreeTest.java:1359)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.ogm.annotations.EntityFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 73 more
```

What am I doing wrong and how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue with a correct dependencies:

```
    <spring-data-neo4j.version>4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-data-neo4j.version>
    <neo4j-ogm.version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</neo4j-ogm.version>
```

**UPDATED**

My Neo4jConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Neo4jConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("com.example.model");
    }

}
```

ogm.properties file from resources

```
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver
URI=bolt://neo4j:xxxxxx@localhost
```

Comment: Thanks! Same problem here :) I've changed the versions and now interface Neo4jRepository (which extend all my repositories) does not exist. Do you know if there is a migration guide to 4.2.x or somegthing similar? Anyway, I don't believe upgrade is an option for me right now...any alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: In case of upgrade please use GraphRepository instead.

Comment: Thanks @alexanoid. Maybe I'll give it a try to the upgrade, but I'm seing there are more changes in Neo4jConfiguration as well... Thanks anyway!

Comment: np, I have added my Neo4jConfig into the answer above + ogm.properties file